# I get 'usertable matching query does not exist' error in django when I try enter the wrong username and login

Tags: django-views

```
def userlogin(request):
if request.POST:
    email=request.POST['email']
    password=request.POST['password']

    user=usertable.objects.get(email=email)
    if user:
        if user.password==password:\
            return render(request, "app/index.html")
        else:
            message="password does not match!"
            return render(request,"app/login.html",{'msg':message})
    else:
        message="user does not exist"
        return render(request,"app/login.html",{'msg':message})

    `here usertable is the table`
```

I expect to get a "user does not exist" message but insted get this "usertable DoesNotMatch error". I replaced .get() method by .filter() method.
when I do , the problem reverses, i.e i dont get a problem with the username but will get a problem with the password. and also.